# Why shouldn't I put the "else" same level with "if" in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I put else the same level  with if, the program didn't work when i called my function. (little star in jupyter notebook). But when I pulled "else" one level behind, everything was ok. The function is meant to return the number of prime numbers that exist up to and including a given number. Here is my code :

```
def count_primes(num):

    primes = list(range (3,num,2))

    digit = 3

    if num < 2:
       return 0

    while digit <= num:
          for x in range (3, digit, 2):
        
              if digit % x == 0:
                 primes.remove(digit)
                 digit += 2
                 break
          else:
                 digit += 2

    primes.insert(0,2)

print (primes)   
return len(primes)
```

Comment: fix indentations in above code

Comment: that `else` applys to the `for`, not the `if`

Comment: The answer is "Because that makes it wrong".

Comment: I edited and fixed the indentations. @Sociopath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you do not want to get the else in the for loop. You just need to return the prime numbers once.

For example if I make the program just to check whether a number is prime or not -

```
    if num > 1:
   # check for factors
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")if num > 1:
   # check for factors
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
```

PS: I have not included if the number is one or less.

I do not want to print Number is not prime several times. Because if I put else inside the loop, it will run every time if fails.

Comment: Is it like: the for loops ends when "if" statement is not True, than it jumps back to the while loop and do the "else" instead of "for" loop, than goes all the way top of the while loop.

Comment: Sorry I am new at programming and trying to learn it by myself, so It can be confusing for me sometimes

Comment: It always go from the top down so remember that if you have created 2 loops 1 inside another so the first loop will run once and you will get in the second loop and it will run until the condition mentioned then the first loop will increment and again the process will repeat. You will get it with some practice.